# Which is more powerful, the authenticated user's role or the bucket's policy?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-iam

I have an identity pool which has the following policy attached to the authenticated users role

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject",
                "s3:ListBucket",
                "s3:CreateBucket"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::*"
        }
    ]
}
```

And I have the following bucket policy applied on an S3 bucket called `testbucketoz123`

```
{
    "Version": "2012-10-17",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCognitoUserAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": [
                "s3:PutObject",
                "s3:GetObject"
            ],
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketoz123/*",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalTag/CognitoIdentityId": "099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad"
                }
            }
        },
        {
            "Sid": "AllowCognitoUserAccess",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": "*",
            "Action": "s3:ListBucket",
            "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketoz123",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "aws:PrincipalTag/CognitoIdentityId": "099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Correct me if I am missing something, but I think the above bucket policy allows just the user with the Cognito Identity ID "099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad" to perform the actions "s3:PutObject" and "s3:GetObject" on all objects within the S3 bucket `testbucketoz123`. It also allows the same user to list the contents of the `testbucketoz123` bucket.

My questions are:

- Can any authenticated user access the 'testbucketoz123' bucket or just the Cognito User  with the Cognito Identity ID `099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad`?

---

#### Note

I have set the same bucket policy, but the authenticated users were having the `AWSS3FullAccess` Permission, and the result was:

- Every authenticated user has access to the 'testbucketoz123' bucket despite the bucket policy.

I assume that if a user has the `AWSS3FullAccess` policy, it would allow them full access to all S3 buckets within your account, regardless of any other policies that may be in place.

If so, how to limit access of a bucket to just one Cognito user? Thanks in advance

Comment: Yes, as long as _any_ policy (be it a bucket policy or an IAM policy) grants access, then that user will have access. I would advise against using that first policy, since it is granting any of the Cognito-authenticated users permission to create any number of buckets and upload/download/list the contents of ALL buckets in the account -- including buckets that _you_ have created to store program code and confidential data. Is there any particular reason why you are granting such permissions on _any_ Amazon S3 bucket?

Comment: @JohnRotenstein so for example if I gave the authenticated users very simple permissions instead of giving them access on all S3 buckets, and I set the bucket policy for the ```testbucketoz123``` to the one above, only the user with the Cognito Identity ID ```099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad``` will be able to perform the actions on this bucket right? and please is the bucket policy correct or am I setting something wrong?

Comment: You said _"I have an identity pool which has the following policy attached to the authenticated users role"_, and the policy shown will let all of those users create/upload/download/list _ANY_ bucket in your AWS Account. That can be quite dangerous. For example, any of those users can view any objects uploaded by other users. They could upload large files (eg movies) and you would be charged for the storage and for the Data Transfer costs whenever somebody downloads those files. It doesn't matter that you have then created a Bucket Policy with limited permissions -- all policies will apply.

Comment: @JohnRotenstein yes that's right, maybe I didn't make it clear in my comment, what I wanted to say is that let's forget that I gave the authenticated users to create/upload/download/list ANY bucket in my AWS Account, and instead, I just gave them simple permissions, for example just to read from a bucket called ```test987```, and on the other hand I have set the bucket policy for the ```testbucketoz123``` S3 Bucket to the one above (Check above "And I have the following bucket policy applied on an S3 bucket called testbucketoz123"), my question is (Check my following comment)

Comment: @JohnRotenstein Will only the Cognito user with the Cognito Identity ID ```099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad``` be able to perform the GET/PUT/LIST actions on ```testbucketoz123``` bucket right?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. However, if any IAM Users have been given permissions to access this S3 bucket (or _all_ buckets in the account), then they will _also_ be able to access this bucket. If your goal is to provide storage to individual users, it is better to grant access based on the _path_ within a bucket, rather than creating a separate bucket per user. See: [IAM policy elements: Variables and tags - AWS Identity and Access Management](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/IAM/latest/UserGuide/reference_policies_variables.html)

Answer (score 0):

> [Bucket policies and user policies](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/userguide/using-iam-policies.html) are two access policy options available for granting permission to your Amazon S3 resources.

This means either can `Allow` access, and your first policy allows access to `testbucketoz123` and it's objects.

In addition to the `Allow` on `aws:PrincipalTag/CognitoIdentityId` you can add a corresponding `Deny` when the `Condition` is not met.  However, **be careful** not to over-Deny Actions, otherwise your administrators will not be able to manage the bucket.

```
    {
        "Sid": "AllowCognitoUserAccess",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketoz123/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "aws:PrincipalTag/CognitoIdentityId": "099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad"
            }
        }
    },
    {
        "Sid": "DenyNonCognitoUserAccess",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": [
            "s3:PutObject",
            "s3:GetObject"
        ],
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::testbucketoz123/*",
        "Condition": {
            "StringNotEquals": {
                "aws:PrincipalTag/CognitoIdentityId": "099702b2-0c2e-42ce-8e27-3012ab6032ad"
            }
        }
    }
```